# Order of member fields in Enum

Tags: java, enums

Why the order of declaration important for Java enums, I mean why does this give (compile time) errors

```
public enum ErrorCodes {
    public int id;
    Undefined;
}
```

but this one is fine:

```
public enum ErrorCodes {
    Undefined;
    public int id;

}.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this is the syntax for enums.  It could allow different orders however this may have been open to mistakes such as forgetting to place a type on a field and turning it into a enum value.

EDIT: The reason I say they could be in any order is that fields, methods, initialisers and constructors can be in any order. I believe the restriction is valid if it is to reduce mistakes.  Even though fields/constructors/methods can be in any order its very common to see them in that order for readability.

Comment: +1 - If the order wasn't tied down, enums would be harder to read, the syntax would be harder to parse, and syntax error messages would be less comprehensible.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a very satisfying answer, but it's just how enums are defined in Java. See section [8.9 Enums](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9) in The Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

Java Enum is a special kind of class. Its simple and mostly useful form does not contain custom fields:

```
public enum ErrorCodes {
    Undefined, Defined, Foo, Bar
}
```

Compiler magic creates class that looks approximately like the following:

```
public class ErrorCodes {
    public final static ErrorCodes Undefined = new ErrorCodes();
    public final static ErrorCodes Defined = new ErrorCodes();
    public final static ErrorCodes Foo = new ErrorCodes();
    public final static ErrorCodes Bar = new ErrorCodes();
}
```

This compiler magic expects the fields definition right after the enum header.

Sun were so kind to allow us to add such fields that follow the definition of eunum members: 
    public enum ErrorCodes {
        Undefined, Defined, Foo, Bar;
        private String myField;
    }

This is the reason that your custom code always must be defined **after** the enum fields.

Comment: It is not "compiler magic" ... it is common or garden "syntax".